# Insert question mark(?) into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, unicode, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone emoticons insert into MySQL but become blank value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509668/iphone-emoticons-insert-into-mysql-but-become-blank-value)
>   [insert an Unicode character in databsae](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123895/insert-an-unicode-character-in-databsae)

i am trying to insert an Unicode character like : (  ) in the database but when i insert that (  ) in textarea it adds a question mark(?) in the database ?

The **DB**:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `msg` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8_mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

`insert.php` to add data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>my page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="insert-ok.php">
      <p>
        <label for="textarea"></label>
        <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
    </body>
```

`insert-ok.php` to insert and view data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>my data</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","4530");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); 
mysql_select_db("test", $con); 
$post= $_POST['textarea'];
$sql = "insert into t1 values('$id','$post')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);

$result=mysql_query("select * from t1 ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo $row['msg'].'<br>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you posting the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123895/insert-an-unicode-character-in-databsae

Comment: the problem is in Question mark now

Answer (score 0):

`SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

- Source: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Another thing is (as [documentation says](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)) deprecated `mysql_` doesn't support Charsets.

Comment: But to be honest i am not sure is `mysql_` supports `uttf8mb4`.

Comment: if it v5.5 it support it ... but it didn't work

Comment: i mean deprecated `mysql_` functions. You should use PDO or preffered `mysqli_`. Please read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php

Comment: Also, collate is only about sort precedence

Comment: the answer is : change the field type from varchar to blob

Comment: @aboji this is only workaround, and bad practice. You should keep text data in text fields